# Can I always find an unitary operator $B$ such that $\{A,B\}= 0$ for a given, unitary operator $A$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, anticommutator

Considering an arbitrary unitary operator $A$, what is the least criteria this operator must satisfy in order that it is possible to find at least another unitary operator $B$ that anti-commutes with it ? Is there a generic way to build this operator $B$ ?

For example, if one consider a displacement operator $\mathcal{D}(\alpha_1) = \exp(\alpha_1\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\alpha_1^*\hat{a})$, then, if $\alpha_1 \neq 0$, it is always possible to find a displacement operator that is anti-commuting with it. If $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha_1\alpha_2^*) = \pm\pi/2$, then we have $\{\mathcal{D}(\alpha_1),\mathcal{D}(\alpha_2)\} = 0$.

Comment: You're already given a counterexample with the identity, so how could you be interested in a proof that it's always possible? What's the exact question here?

Comment: maybe you should ask the least criteria that any linear operator must satisfy, in order that it is possible to find at least another operator that anti commutes with it.

Comment: To reopen this question (v4), consider to make a precise statement without simple counterexamples, plus consider to harmonize title and main body.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Case 1:* Operators over finite dimensional space**:

First, assume operators are from a *finite* dimensional vector space named $V$ to $V$. Let $N=dim(V)$.

We are seeking a unitary operator that anti-commutes with $A$. Let $\{e_i\}$ an *orthogonal basis* for $V$ and $\sigma$ a permutation from $\{1,...,N\}$ to itself. Define $B$ by $B(e_i)=e_{\sigma(i)}$. It can be shown that $B$ is unitary since its matrix columns are perpendicular. Using this motivation, we find a necessary and sufficient condition for the question. The condition is:

> if $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with $K_i$ independent eigenvectors, then there is a unitary operator that anti-commutes with $A$ if and only if $-\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with exactly $K_i$ independent eigenvectors.

Now let's prove it. First consider $A$ meets the condition. Let $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k\}$ positive eigenvalues of $A$. Let's show orthogonal eigenvectors of $\pm\lambda_i$ with $e^{\pm}_{i,j}$ that $j\in\{1,...,K_i\}$. Define $B$ by $B(e^{\pm}_{i,j})=e^{\mp}_{i,j}$. Indeed, we have defined a permutation from $\{1,...,N\}$ and so $B$ is unitary. $B$ anti-commutes with $A$ iff for every $e^{\pm}_{i,j}$, $AB(e^{\pm}_{i,j})+BA(e^{\pm}_{i,j})=0$. It can be seen:

$AB(e^{\pm}_{i,j})=A(e^{\mp}_{i,j})=\mp\lambda_ie^{\mp}_{i,j}$

$BA(e^{\pm}_{i,j})=\pm\lambda_iB(e^{\pm}_{i,j})=\pm\lambda_ie^{\mp}_{i,j}$

Thus, $B$ is unitary and anti-commutes with $A$.

Now consider there is a unitary operator named $B$ that anti-commutes with $A$. $A$ is unitary, so it is normal operator means $A^{\dagger}A=AA^{\dagger}$. Thus it can be represented in a diagonal form with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and eigenvectors $\{e_i\}$ that is $i\in\{1,...,N\}$. None of these eigenvalues can be zero since $A$ is invertible. $B$ anti-commutes with $A$, so $AB(e_i)+BA(e_i)=0\Rightarrow (A+\lambda_iI)B(e_i)=0$. $B(e_i)$ is not zero since $B$ is unitary and has inverse. So, $A-(-\lambda_i)I$ is not invertible and so $-\lambda_i$ is eigenvalue of $A$. Now, assume there are $K_i$ independent eigenvectors for $\lambda_i$ and there are $K^{\prime}_i$ independent eigenvectors for $-\lambda_i$. Since $B$ is invertible, so $det(B)\neq0$ and so $B(e_i)$s are independent. Using the above notation, we know $B(e^{+}_{i,j})$ that $j\in\{1,...,K_i\}$ is eigenvector for $-\lambda_i$ and these are independent. So, $K_i\leq K^{\prime}_i$. By the same argument, it can be shown $K^{\prime}_i\leq K_i$. Hence, $K^{\prime}_i=K_i$ and the proof is finished.

***Case 2:* Operators over a separable Hilbert space:**

Now, assume operators are from a separable Hilbert space named $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathcal{H}$ (over real or complex field). It means they have a denumerable set that the set of all finite compositions of its elements is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. In fact, previous case is a special case of this case since a (finite) basis for $V$ is such a set.

$A$ is unitary, so it is normal. The spectral theorem states there is an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$. In the other words, the set of all finite compositions of eigenvectors of $A$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$. $A$ is normal and by definition a normal operator is a continuous operator that commutes with its adjoint. We are seeking another unitary (thus continuous and normal) operator like $B$ that anti-commutes with $A$. Consider $D$ a dense subset of $\mathcal{H}$. It is known that a continuous map from a set $X$ to itself can be uniquely determined by its value over $D$. So it is sufficient to determine $B$ over a dense subset of $\mathcal{H}$. It means it is sufficient $B$ anti-commutes with $A$ over $D$. By this general discussion, we can state a similiar necessary and sufficient condition holds in this case:

> if $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with $K_i=card(M_{\lambda_i})$ where $M_{\lambda_i}$ is a (linear algebra) basis for eigenspace of $\lambda_i$, then there is a unitary operator that anti-commutes with $A$ if and only if $-\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ which $K_i=card(M_{-\lambda_i})$.

First consider $A$ meets the condition. $A$ by spectral theorem has a orthogonal set like $E$ that all finite compositions of $E$ is dense in  $\mathcal{H}$. Then define $B$ in the same manner we did in the previous case by $e_i$s in accordance to $E$. It can be done since it concerns only finite compositions of $E$. It can be verified that $B$ is unitary and anti-commutes with $A$.

Conversely, consider there is a unitary operator anti-commutes with $A$. Again we can show $-\lambda_i$ is eigenvalue of $A$ since $B$ is invertible. $B(e_i)$s are independent (due to finite sums) because $B$ is injective. Thus, one can make a bijection from $M_{\lambda_i}$ to $M_{-\lambda_i}$ and so show they have the same cardinality.

**Remark**: I stated the latter condition using cardinality. $A$ is injective so does not have zero eigenvalue. As I know, eigenspaces for non-zero eigenvalues of self-adjoint operators, are finite so it is not necessary to use *cardinality*. But I am not sure the same holds for unitary (or normal) operators. So I used cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser. Do you know if there is any way to extend this proof to the case of infinite dimension, countable or uncountable ?

Comment: @Dimitri I edited my answer for separable Hilbert space. Hope it be helpful.

Comment: Is it possible to use the same kind of reasoning when the dimension of the space is uncountable ?